# Adding js and css from a module but only to node view, not node edit

Tags: 7, theming

I'm adding js and css from a custom module and it works except for the fact that it also adds to the node edit page which I don't want.

I have this in my custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

// Global node.
$node = menu_get_object();
 if (!empty($node) && $node->type == 'my_node_type') {

// do stuff here like add_js, add_css

  }
}
```

... this works except that it also adds js and css files to the node edit page which I do not want. I've been playing around with this now for a while and any searches I've done have come up blank so I'm out of ideas for now. I suspect I need an extra argument to only add this to a node view and not node edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could verify the 3 argument passed inside the menu item (`node/%node/edit`, `node/%node/delete`, `node/%node/translate`). If this third argument is `null`, you know that it is the node view page.

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) 
{
    // Global node.
    $node = menu_get_object();

    if (!empty($node) && $node->type == 'my_node_type' && arg(2) === null) {
        // do stuff here like add_js, add_css
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A quick, dirty way would be to check the current path for 'edit':

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if (!empty($node) && $node->type == 'my_node_type' && arg(2) != 'edit') {
  // ...
}
```